# Linked Images in PowerPoint 2016 Not Updating Automatically

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint

I used Insert -> Pictures -> Insert and Link to try to link images to slides in PowerPoint. The links show up in the "Edit Links to Files" tab as Manual.
[See here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfPCj.png)

In this image, the "Automatic Update" box is greyed out. Also, when I close the PowerPoint file and reopen, the images still don't update. The images are .png files.

Does anyone know what the issue could be here?